# Error Funcion de laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando realizar un query con lo que me permite Query Builder de laravel, pero no se por que al momento de hacer la siguiente consulta me da un error que no esta definido el id y es la variable que estoy recibiendo en la funcion show.

```
public function show($id)
    {
      $fac = DB::table('fac_enc as fe')
        ->join('fac_det as fd', function ($join) {
            $join->on('fe.id_fac_enc', '=', 'fd.id_fac_enc')
        ->where('fe.id_fac_enc','=',$id);
        })
        ->get();

      return view('facturas.show',compact('fac'));
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien supiera el por que pasa esto, se lo agradecere

Answer (score 1):

Me parece un tanto complejo y re buscado como haces el `join`, pero el asunto parece arreglarse si le pasas la varibale `$id` del modo siguiente:

Tu tienes esta línea de código:

```
 ->join('fac_det as fd', function ($join) {
```

Aquí debes usar `use()` para indicarle que use dentro del contexto de la función anónima una variable que esta por fuera de esta, en este caso `$id`, del modo siguiente:

```
 ->join('fac_det as fd', function ($join) use ($id){
```

Sin embargo al margen de tu pregunta, te recomendaría leer sobre las [relaciones en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) que te permitirán manejar escenarios como el que tratas de resolver con esta consulta con mayor facilidad.

Ejemplo:

El siguiente código me da como error:

> Undefined variable `$nombre`

Pues `$nombre` no existe dentro del contexto de la función anónima.

```
$nombre = "Yo";

$mensaje = function(){
    echo $nombre;
};

$mensaje();
```

Sin embargo ahora haciendo uso de `use($variable)` indicaremos que use una variable externa dentro dle contexto de la función anónima, imprimiendo dicho valor:

```
$nombre = "Yo";

$mensaje = function() use($nombre){
    echo $nombre;
};

$mensaje();
```

Dando como resultado:

> Yo

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Desde [PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arrow.php) tenemos a nuestra disposición el uso de las *funciones flecha*, notemos que el *scope* entre la función anónimas y las funciones flecha difiere

**EJEMPLO**

```
$resultado = 10;

//CON FUNCIONES ANÓNIMAS

$operacion2 = function () use($resultado){
    return $resultado * 10;
};

echo $operacion2();


//CON FUNCIONES FLECHA

$operacion = fn() => $resultado * 10;

echo $operacion();
```

Dando como resultado 100 en ambos casos.

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Funciones anónimas en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: De hecho es un query basado en el query builder que esta en el ejemplo de laravel, pero ya arreglé el inconveniente, no se por qué a veces las cosas no funcionan cuando estan correctas

Comment: lo dejé de la siguiente forma:

Answer (score 0):

Ya me funcionó de hecho no se por que algunas veces las cosas no funcionan aunque estén de forma correcta, el código quedó así:

```
$facturas = DB::table('fac_enc as fe')
                  ->join('fac_det as fd','fe.id_fac_enc','=','fd.id_fac_enc')
                  ->join('producto as p','fd.id_producto','=','p.id_producto')
                  ->join('marca as m','p.id_marca','=','m.id_marca')
                  ->join('categoria as c','p.id_categoria','=','c.id_categoria')
                  ->join('cliente as cli','cli.id_cliente','=','fe.id_cliente')
                  ->where('fe.id_fac_enc','=',$id)
                  ->select('fe.id_fac_enc as id_fac_enc','p.descripcion as producto','m.descripcion as marca','c.descripcion as categoria','precio_venta','cantidad','total','nit','nombre','direccion')
                  ->get();
      return $facturas;
      return view('facturas.show',compact('facturas'));
```

lo que no entiendo es por qué me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si en el resultado en json si aparece ese campo y muestra datos.

Comment: Fíjate que ya había hecho esto también, pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: de hecho esa fue la primera forma en como lo intenté, pero logré solucionarlo, gracias.