# ¿Porqué me dice que no está definido la variable $i dentro de un for?

Tags: php

Tengo un error que me está dando dolor de cabeza... En un bucle for me dice que no tengo definido la variable $i cuando si está. Lo que pasa que estoy usando $i dentro de una función.

Os pego código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar:

```
for ($i=$minimo_normales; $i <= $maximo_normales; $i++) { 
    $array_mayor_igual[$i] = count(array_filter($goles_normales, function ($var) {
        return ($var > $i);
    })) ;
}
```

El error que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea? Yo creo que el problema es por el rango de acceso a la variable dentro de la function pero... No sé como hacerlo.

Saludos!

Comment: Podrías compartir los arrays: `$array_mayor_igual, $goles_normales` y las variables `$minimo_normales, $maximo_normales` ?

Comment: Posible duplicado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270262/error-funcion-de-laravel/270268?r=SearchResults#270268

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale encontré la solución. Intuía que el problema era el rango de acceso a la variable $i. Se tiene que añadir al callback "use" para que tenga acceso. Pego código:

```
for ($i=$minimo_normales; $i <= $maximo_normales; $i++) { 
    $array_mayor_igual[$i] = count(array_filter($goles_normales, function ($var) use ($i) {
        return ($var > $i);
    }));
}
```